# ANGULAR: how to unit test a function with setValueControl

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, controls, angular-test

i'm trying to unit test this simple function that sets controls for each value.

```
fillFormAssociazioneVeicolo() {
    if (this.aaa) {
      setValueControl(
        this.aaa.targaTelaio,
        this.form.get('targaTelaio')
      );
      setValueControl(
        this.aaa.tipoVeicolo,
        this.form.get('tipoVeicolo')
      );
      setValueControl(
        this.aaa.tipoVeicolo?.descrizione,
        this.form.get('descTipoVeicolo')
      );
      setValueControl(
        this.aaa.nomeCognome,
        this.form.get('nomeCognome')
      );
      setValueControl(
        this.aaa.codiceFiscale,
        this.form.get('codiceFiscale')
      );
    }
```

this is what the setValueControl function does:

```
export function setValueControl(
  value: any,
  control: AbstractControl | null,
  disable: boolean = true
) {
  if (control) {
    control.setValue(value);
    if (disable) disableControl(control);
  }
}
```

I've tried this way, but it is not the right answer:

```
it('can fillFormAssociazioneVeicolo', () => {
    component.riempiFormAssociazioneVeicolo();
    expect(setValueControl(component.associazioneVeicolo?.tipoVeicolo,component.form.get('tipoVeicolo')));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, setValueControl is not really nice to unittest because it expects the function "disableControl" to be defined. To make a function well testable, it should not depend on functions on the scope, ideally it should be pure... how ever

```
export function setValueControl(
  value: any,
  control: AbstractControl | null,
  disable: boolean = true
) {
  if (control) {
    control.setValue(value);
    if (disable) control.disable();
  }
}
```

Now you can use spyOn (assuming you are using jasmine) on a mock-object you provided to check if the function works as expected:

```
let controlMock = {
  setValue:(a) => {},
  disable: () => {}
}

const setValueSpy = spyOn(controlMock, 'setValue')
const disableSpy = spyOn(controlMock, 'disable')

setValueControl("ciao", controlMock)

expect(setValueSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("guasto");
expect(disableSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: Argument of type '{ setValue: (a: any) => void; disable: () => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AbstractControl'.
  Type '{ setValue: (a: any) => void; disable: () => void; }' is missing the following properties from type 'AbstractControl': _parent, _asyncValidationSubscription, value, validator, and 42 more.ts(2345). This is the errore showed when I changed the code as you suggested.

Comment: You can use an actual "control" in your test. It was just for the example, how to spy on the functions. E.g: controlMock = new FormControl();